# How to copy folders with Batch file which does not start with an underscore?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to copy all files and folders which don't start with an underscore in its file/directory name using a batch file. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Yes, this is possible! Get a list of files and filter it with __FIND__ or __FINDSTR__ using option `/V` and process the filtered list with __FOR__ for copying the files or folders. Or use __XCOPY__ or even better __ROBOCOPY__ which support copying files and folders and supporting both an exclude option. You can get help on all commands by opening a command prompt window and run the command with option `/?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From cmdline:

```
For /f %i in ('dir /b ^| findstr /v /b "_"') do echo %i
```

In a batch file:

```
For /f %%i in ('dir /b ^| findstr /v /b "_"') do echo %%i
```

`Findstr /v` excludes specific items specified in the double quotes.

To do it through all subfolders add `/s`

```
 For /f %%i in ('dir /s /b ^| findstr \[^_][^\\]*$') do echo %%i
```

Comment: I think you need to add the `/B` switch to the `FINDSTR` command.  The user requested folders that **do not start** with and `_`.

Comment: For the recursive approach adding `/B` (or using search string `^_`) won't work, but you could change the search string to this: `\\[^_][^\\]*$` (remove `/V` then!)